# validate date tru time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a date—`start_time` and `end_time`—and I want to validate if the time is taken in the particular date. I read about scope validation:

```
validates :date ,:uniqueness => { :scope => :timeEnd, :timeStart }
```

but I guess I have to do something else I think this is a implementation problem not technically a logic problem or error bugs like that stuffs.

Do guys have suggestions for how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to write a [conditional validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation).

This may or may not be the actual code you need, but it should point you in the right direction.

```ruby
validates :date, :if => :within_range?

def within_range?
    timeStart...timeEnd === date
end
```